# How to replace this sequence of characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a long string and when I find the sequence of three characters consisting of `0x0d 0x0a 0x20` I will replace these three with `0x5c 0x6e 0x20`.
The problem is that I don't get a match after `0x0d 0x0a 0x20` in the first if clause below.

```
 if (allText.IndexOf(@"\r\n ") != -1)
 {
     allText = Regex.Replace(allText, @"\r\n ", @"\n ");                                     
     if ( allText.IndexOf(@"\n ") != -1)
     {
     }
 }
```

//Tony

Comment: what is in allText?

Comment: It's just  a lot of text

Comment: does it contains @"\r\n "... if yes, it should pass the first if condition

Comment: Remove `@` prefix from strings. "\" is treated differently in verbatim strings.

Answer (score 1):

string is immutable so you need to assign it to new one or the same.

if i get you right you can change all the instances of `0x0d 0x0a 0x20` in your allTest string to `0x5c 0x6e 0x20` by using regular string Method Replace.

```
string textThatShouldBeReplaced = @"0x0d 0x0a 0x20";
string textToReplace = @"0x5c 0x6e 0x20";

if (allText.IndexOf(@"\r\n ") != -1)
   {
      if( allText.IndexOf(@"\n ") != -1)
        {
           allText = allText.Replace(textThatShouldBeReplaced,textToReplace);
        }
 }
```